# Overriding parent control's datacontext with local datacontext

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have a Groupbox in which i have multiple Textboxes. All these Textbox derive their Datacontext from that of Groupbox but one of the Textbox in the group needs a different Datacontext.

```
<GroupBox Header="My Group" Height="150" Width="1132" DataContext="{Binding ContextA}" >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label x:Name="lblA"  Content="Policy Number:" Margin="6,12,970,92" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="txtbA" Margin="155,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding ValueA}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                                    <Label x:Name="lblB"  Content="Policy Type:" Margin="612,10,334,88" Height="30"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="txtbB" Margin="801,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" DataContext="{Binding ContextB}" Text="{Binding ValueB}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </GroupBox>
```

In the above code `txtbA` uses the `Datacontext` same as that of Groupbox.
I want `txtbB` to have a separate `Datacontext`i.e. `ContextB`

But the `ContextB` is not getting assigned to `txtbB`. How to solve the problem?

Note:
`ContextA`and `ContextB`= list of Entity Framework models.

Answer (score 1):

**WPF binding engine look for property in current DataContext.** So, in your case binding engine is looking for property `ContextB` in class `ContextA` since textBox is inheriting DataContext from parent GroupBox.

What you can do is use more verbose definition for `ContextA` like this:

```
<GroupBox Header="My Group" Height="150" Width="1132"
          DataContext="{Binding}"> <-- HERE Or can remove setting DC altogether.
   <Grid>
     <Label x:Name="lblA"  Content="Policy Number:" Margin="6,12,970,92" />
     <TextBox x:Name="txtbA" Margin="155,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap"
              Text="{Binding ContextA.ValueA}" <-- HERE
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="278" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
     <Label x:Name="lblB"  Content="Policy Type:" Margin="612,10,334,88"
            Height="30"/>
     <TextBox x:Name="txtbB" Margin="801,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Height="24" 
              TextWrapping="Wrap" DataContext="{Binding ContextB}"
              Text="{Binding ValueB}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278"/>
   </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```